# CLion how to specify remote dir for .clion.resources

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, clion, jetbrains-ide

How do I change the dir where .clion.resources is stored on the remote host?
Goes to /tmp by default

```
[8/31/2020 5:17 PM] Failed to transfer file 'C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.1\bin\gdb\renderers\libstdcxx\__init__.py': could not create folder "sftp://remotebox/tmp/.clion.resources/7aa6df78-4ca6-41da-b851-950e31119c77". (Permission denied)
```